# Android how I can parse and consume webservices?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, android-ksoap2

How I can parse this type of webservices in android? Kindly see the below images.  I created this webservices in .net, now I want to parse and consume that Login webservice in Android.  Kindly anyone help it would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
SOAP 1.1

 The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be  replaced with actual values.

POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Login"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <username>string</username>
  <password>string</password>
  <apptypecode>string</apptypecode>
  </Login>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
 <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <LoginResult>string</LoginResult>
 </LoginResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please remove the images. Just post a couple of code block with text. Use cpy/paste.

Comment: @greenapps ok wait a min :)

Answer (score 1):

It's "KSOAP  webService", they have lot of tutorial.

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/03/tutorial-78-using-ksoap2-in-android/

Exemple for login webservice
https://github.com/thira/blog-demos/tree/master/android-kSOAP2-example

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-java-web-service-in-android/

Comment: Anthone thanks for ur reply,kindly can u suggest me the tutorial in which the login screen webservices wil be consumed??Thanks again

Comment: I have edit my post. But if you have choixe, I recommand you to use REST WebService with JSON

Comment: ok i am leaving office now,will be checking it tommorrow bro :)